# How can I replace last string apartition on all words in JavaScript with replace()?

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how can I change the last string aparitions of all words in JavaScript, for example, change the phrase "Trees are expensives" for "Treis ari expensivis"

I tried to use a solution that I also found on this page, but it only replaced a single character until its last appearance, not in all the sentences

Comment: What chars are you trying to replace with what other chars? What are the actual rules?

Comment: I want to change the letters o and i, but it has to be changed at the last occurrence of each word

Comment: Why does `Trees` turn into `Threis`? Where does the `h` come from?

Comment: Which is the source and which is the result?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```js
const strs = 'Trees are expensives'.split(' ')
const newstrs = []

for (const str of strs) {
  const strsarr = Array.from(str)
  const i = strsarr.findLastIndex(c => c === 'e')
  strsarr.splice(i, 1, 'i')
  newstrs.push(strsarr.join(''))
}

const result = newstrs.join(' ')

console.log(result)
```

Comment: This doesn't produce the desired result.

Comment: Please post your code as an executable Stack Snippet, so we can see the result without having to copy/paste.

Comment: Thank you, Barmar. I fixed the code and added an executable Stack Snippet.